# can i programmatically insert office addin manifest file in an excel file file

Tags: excel, office365, office-js

i have a question.

**is it possible to add office add-in manifest file in an excel file programmatically.**

we are providing a on-premise solution to users. we have created a office manifest file and the office add-in is hosted on an internal server, when our product is installed we modify the manifest file to have correct name of hosting server.

to be able to user the office addin, our user need to open the excel and add the shared folder path where the manifest file is available as secure catalog which is lot of manual intervention.

i want to grammatically add manifest file in excel after the server name is changed in manifest file and then our user will download the excel file and because the manifest file is already integrated, in excel it will start the office addin.

let me know if its possible to addin office addin through manifest file in an excel programmatically.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found the relevant content, I am afraid that such requirements cannot be realized.

Comment: This question was cross-posted to GitHub and has been answered there:  https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/259#issuecomment-427525471.